# ASP.NET Login via Custom WCF Rest Call

Tags: asp.net, wcf, asp.net-membership

I'm writing an admin panel in ASP.NET for an existing set of web service calls. My goal is to use some of the existing login stuff (locking out pages if your not logged in) etc but using my login mechanism. This works by hitting an http post request with a username and password, if you're good you get a session id back, if not you get a 401. Here is the WCF for that:

```
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/Login/", Method = "POST")]
        public String Login(User user)
        {     
            // If we are good return sessiond id
            // Otherwise throw 401 etc
```

So to get this working in ASP.Net what is needed?

I think this:

- Implement a user that overrides MembershipUser and has a session id in it.
- Implement a membership provider that overrides MembershipProvider and does all the WCF calls etc.
- In the Web.Config set up a custom membership provider.

Is this correct or am I missing something major?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than do this yourself, you might want to take a look at the [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386582.aspx) [Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398990.aspx) Services.

Before you go down this route, be aware that the authentication services supports login and logout, but that is about it. The usual `Membership` methods such as `CreateUser` aren't available. If you need them, you'll need to create three projects:

1. A WCF Service Application with a single service called `WCFMembershipService` that wraps the core Membership Provider requirements, i.e. calling `Membership.Provider.Method()`. Configure the standard `SQLMembershipProvider` in the `web.config`, and
2. A custom membership provider to be used in the ASP.NET application that calls your WCF service from step 1, and
3. An ASP.NET Application with the custom membership provider configured

You will find that the `Membership` and `Role` providers are extremely easy, but the `Profile` provider is more challenging, because you cannot serialize the default properties that the provider requires, such as `SettingsPropertyValueCollection`.

In this case, you would need to convert the `SettingsPropertyValueCollection` into a serializable type first, and then reconstruct it at the other end. Probably a `Dictionary<string, string>()` would suffice.